# rigify relink constraints don't work

Tags: rigify, bone.constraints

When I build a custom armature, I want to generate bones in armature as the target for a `basic.raw_copy` skeleton constraint. I looked up blender manual and some forums, tried it a few times, and it succeeded in making the generated bone the parent, but did not replace the bone constraint target with the bone in the constraint name. Did I do something wrong?

[image: This is the basic.raw_copy setting]

[image: 2]

Try adding `@target bone` after the bone constraint name

[image: 3]

No autofill

[image: 4]

Try replacing the name of the bone constraint with `@target bone`

[image: 5]

No autofill

[image]

Here's what I found on the Internet.

[image]

[image]